# Create a new categorical "comparison detection" column based on two other columns in R (nine option answers)

Tags: r

This is a bit different than other conditional column creations. I want to build a column, "vs", based on two other categorical columns, "matched_apple" and "matched_pear", which each have 3 answer choices or "levels", like so:

```
matched_apple: C, CG, G, C, CG, G, C, CG, G
matched_pear: G, C, CG, CG, G, C, C, CG, G
```

desired outcome (i do not want "vs" output to contain the entire column names of matched_apple and matched_pear, just "apple" and "pear"):

```
vs: apple=C/pear=G, apple=CG/pear=C, apple=G/pear=CG, apple=C/pear=CG, apple=CG/pear=G, apple=G/pear=C, apple=C/pear=C, apple=CG/pear=CG, apple=G/pear=G
```

basically, i want to create a column that detects answers of matched_apple and matched_pear, and spits out a simple detection of apple/pear answers in a new column.

I can figure out how to create a binary conditional variable, but cannot figure out how best to create a multiple level conditional code to get my desire output. this is my current code:

```
library(dplyr)
df <-df %>%
     mutate(vs = c("", "apple=G/pear=CG")[(apple == "G" & 
           pear == "CG")+1])
```

which essentially only creates a one level variable. i tried adding to the mutate() equation, but then i end up getting an error...i cannot think of another better way to approach this other than simply doing it manually. any help/suggestions would be very appreciated!!

Comment: does this do what you are looking for?      df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(vs = paste0("apple=", matched_apple, "/", "pear=",matched_pear))

Comment: if I understand you correctly you are looking for matches of apple and pears and get this as a binary response? If so, try this - just added an additional line to the mutate:    df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(vs = paste0("apple=", matched_apple, "/", "pear=",matched_pear),
                vs2 = ifelse(matched_apple == matched_pear, 1, 0))

Comment: @DPH hi, i have one last question if you have the time to help!! so this dplyr mutate() function is really helpful, and i was wondering if there is also a way to revise it so that it does a less than/greater than/equal to comparison? so if matched_apple=2, matched_pear=-2, the vs output shows "apple>pear, and if equal shows apple=pear, and if less than shows "apple<pear"? thanks a lot!!

Comment: If you want more than a simple ifelse(), meaning more than two outcomes, you can put another ifelse() inside the responses OR you can use a case_when(). Have a read here: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/case_when.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to convesation in the comments this seems to be the answer:

```
library(dplyr)
    df %>% dplyr::mutate(vs = paste0("apple=", matched_apple, "/", "pear=",matched_pear))
```